# Return Promise { "_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null, } in REDUX Reducer React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

This is my code in using `REDUX` :

**ApiChartingReducer.js**

```
    const ApiChartingMenuInitial = {
        apiData: []
    };
    
    export const ApiChartingMenuReducer = (state = ApiChartingMenuInitial, action) => {      
        switch (action.type) {
            case GET_MENU_CHART:                    
                 const getData = async () => {                             
                    try {
                        const response = await ApiChartingAxios.get('/ApiChartingMenu',{
                            params: null
                        });          
                        console.log(response.data.Data) // Data Exists
                        return response.data.Data;
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }                
                    return response.data.Data;                
                };    
                            
                console.log(getData());  // data not exists            
                // return {...state, apiData: getData()}
                
            default: 
                return state;
        }    
    };
```

In this line :

`console.log(response.data.Data) // Data Exists`

But in this line :

`console.log(getData());  // Data not exists`

and return :

```
    Promise {
      "_U": 0,
      "_V": 0,
      "_W": null,
      "_X": null,
    }
```

I cannot use `useState` in my `redux reducer` file. So How I can get my response data in `getData()` ?

Comment: It's a Promise. You have to await the call. `await getData()`

Comment: when i put await getData()  it return error : Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Comment: That's because you are using `await` inside a function that is not asynchronous. I would suggest you to call your API outside the reducer and then use the response to update the store.

Comment: could you give an example of how it is look like ?

Comment: I put it outside and still have null result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Redux reducer, you are not allowed to execute any asynchronous code.

A Redux reducer has to be a pure function without side effects.

Usually in Redux, you would do the fetching either outside of Redux or in a middleware like a thunk, and then dispatch an action with the data that was loaded, which will then be handled in the reducer.

Generally: you are writing a very outdated style of Redux here. Since 2019, the recommended style of Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, immutable reducer logic, createStore or connect/mapStateToProps. You are very likely following outdated documentation. The new style is only 1/4 of the code and a lot less error-prone.

I would recommend you to follow [the official Redux "Essentials" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts), which will teach you the new style and also goes over different methods of data fetching in the chapters 5, 7 and 8.

If you insist that you want to continue learning this old style of Redux, you can also look into the [Redux Fundamentals](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-1-overview) tutorial, which shows the old style to explain some of the internals of Redux for those who are interested in that. Chapter 6 is all about data fetching.